# How to programmatically close bootstrap 5 offcanvas in Next Js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, bootstrap-5

I use using bootstrap 5 in my NextJs app my installing like this:
`npm install bootstrap` and imported the necessary files into my project via _app.js like this:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'

...

useEffect(() => {
    import("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap");
}, []);
```

Now the problem is that when I open the offcanvas modal and click a link from there, the offcanvas stays open after the page changes, instead of closing. How do I programmatically close the offcanvas when the pathname changes and only when the offcanvas is active. Thank you

**NB: I am not using react-bootstrap**

Comment: Why are you importing within a useEffect ?

Even if not using react-bootstrap, sounds like you need some state that determines if the modal is open. Then add an onClick handler to the link to set the state to closed

Answer (score 0):

Recently I ran into the same problem, but here is how I got things working.

First of I do not think you are importing bootstrap in to your nextjs app the right way, but what works work. However I think you should import bootstrap into your nextjs app this way.

```
useEffect(() => {
    typeof document !== undefined
      ? require("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap")
      : null;
  }, []);
```

I don't want to make this too long, so lets dive straight into creating the solution. First you have to create a custom function to close the offCanvas when you click your link.

```
const topicRef = useRef(null);

const closeOffCanvas = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    const bootstrap = require("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap");

    var myOffcanvas = topicRef.current;
    var bsOffcanvas = bootstrap.Offcanvas.getInstance(myOffcanvas);

    bsOffcanvas.hide();
  };
```

Now create your link like so and call the function we just created

```
<Link href={`/article/18004/close-bootstrap-5-offcanvas-in-next-js`} passHref>
 <a href="#" onClick={closeOffCanvas}>navigate to page then close offCanvas</a>
</Link>
```

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Here's what ended up working for me:
I was importing individual bootstrap modules instead of all the modules, and when you do that, I noticed that the global `window.bootstrap` object does not get set.
So I created a `utility/bootstrap.ts` to initialize my subset of bootstrap correctly:

```
import type {
  Alert,
  Button,
  Carousel,
  Collapse,
  Dropdown,
  Modal,
  Offcanvas,
  Popover,
  ScrollSpy,
  Tab,
  Toast,
  Tooltip,
} from 'bootstrap';

export async function initBootstrap(): Promise<void> {
  if (typeof document !== 'undefined' && typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    const [buttonModule, carouselModule, dropdownModule, offcanvasModule] = await Promise.all([
      !window.bootstrap?.Button ? import('bootstrap/js/dist/button') : undefined,
      !window.bootstrap?.Carousel ? import('bootstrap/js/dist/carousel') : undefined,
      !window.bootstrap?.Dropdown ? import('bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown') : undefined,
      !window.bootstrap?.Offcanvas ? import('bootstrap/js/dist/offcanvas') : undefined,
    ]);
    if (!window.bootstrap) {
      window.bootstrap = {
        Button: undefined as unknown as Button & typeof Button,
        Carousel: undefined as unknown as Carousel & typeof Carousel,
        Dropdown: undefined as unknown as Dropdown & typeof Dropdown,
        Offcanvas: undefined as unknown as Offcanvas & typeof Offcanvas,
        Alert: undefined as unknown as Alert & typeof Alert,
        Collapse: undefined as unknown as Collapse & typeof Collapse,
        Modal: undefined as unknown as Modal & typeof Modal,
        Popover: undefined as unknown as Popover & typeof Popover,
        ScrollSpy: undefined as unknown as ScrollSpy & typeof ScrollSpy,
        Tab: undefined as unknown as Tab & typeof Tab,
        Toast: undefined as unknown as Toast & typeof Toast,
        Tooltip: undefined as unknown as Tooltip & typeof Tooltip,
      };
    }
    if (buttonModule) {
      window.bootstrap.Button ||= buttonModule.default;
    }
    if (carouselModule) {
      window.bootstrap.Carousel ||= carouselModule.default;
    }
    if (dropdownModule) {
      window.bootstrap.Dropdown ||= dropdownModule.default;
    }
    if (offcanvasModule) {
      window.bootstrap.Offcanvas ||= offcanvasModule.default;
    }
  }
}
```

You need to install `@bootstrap/types` for the type import to work properly.
Then, in my component, in my case it was Next Js' `_app.tsx` I asynchronously initialize bootstrap using my utility:

```
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  useEffect(() => {
    initBootstrap();
  }, []);
  return (
    <main>
      <Header />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      <Footer />
    </main>
  );
```

Which allows bootstrap to correctly find the offcanvas, rather than creating duplicates. Something like this:

```
export function Header() {
  const offcanvasElRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const closeOffcanvas = () => {
    const offcanvas = window?.bootstrap?.Offcanvas?.getInstance(offcanvasElRef.current as Element);
    offcanvas?.hide();
  };
  return (
    <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvas" aria-labelledby="offcanvasLabel" ref={offcanvasElRef}>
      <div class="offcanvas-header">
        <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasLabel">Offcanvas</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="offcanvas-body">
        Content for the offcanvas goes here. You can place just about any Bootstrap component or custom elements here.
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Import like this:-

```
useEffect(() => {
    import("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle");
  }, []);
```